# Angular Dynamic Forms and JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I am working on a JHipster project (monolith, angular 4 currently) and recently have been investigating the use of dynamic forms.

I came across the following:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-json-schema-form

Should JHipster move to natively support this feature ?

Any advise on embracing dynamic forms into the current jhipster generated client side typescript code ?

I am thinking of modifying the client side model objects manually to incorporate form data that can be be used in dynamic forms.. and removing most of the HTML form code.

Thanks,
Fergal

Comment: Angular Formly
https://formly-js.github.io/ngx-formly/